# PIC16F1517 timer0 does not work

Tags: c, pickit

I am trying to use Timer0 to control a blinking LED, but I am having some difficulties... the LED never turns on.

I referred to [this tutorial](https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/PIC16f877a_Timer) to set things up, but I still can't understand it, could you please tell me where the problem is?

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#define SBIT_PS2 2

volatile unsigned char value = 0;

void timer_isr(void)
{
  if (TMR0IF == 1)
  {
    value =~ value; // complement the value for blinking the LEDs
    TMR0 = 101; // Load the timer value. Note: Timervalue is 101 instead of 100 as Timer0 needs two instruction cycles to start incrementing TMR0
    TMR0IF=0; // Clear timer interrupt flag 
  }
}

/*
Main application
*/
void main(void)
{
  // initialize the device
  SYSTEM_Initialize();

  // When using interrupts, you need to set the Global and Peripheral Interrupt Enable bits
  // Use the following macros to:
  // Enable the Global Interrupts
  INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable();
  // Enable the Peripheral Interrupts
  INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();
  // Disable the Global Interrupts
  //INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptDisable();
  // Disable the Peripheral Interrupts
  //INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptDisable();
  uint16_t dutycycle;
  TRISD=0x00; // Configure PORTD as output to blink the LEDs

  OPTION_REG = (1<<SBIT_PS2); // Timer0 with external freq and 32 as prescalar
  TMR0 = 0; // Load the time value for 1ms delay
  TMR0IE = 1; // Enable timer interrupt bit in PIE1 register
  GIE = 1; // Enable Global Interrupt
  PEIE = 1; // Enable the Peripheral Interrupt 
     
  while (1) {
    WB_PORT = value;
    LR1_PORT = value;
  }
}
```

Supplement: my pin settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Because there is too little information about PIC in Chinese...

Answer (score 2):

It could be the classic missing volatile bug. Change the declaration to `volatile unsigned char value = 0;`

You should also make a habit of using `stdint.h` and `uint8_t` instead. The `char` type in C has implementation-defined signedness, so it is unsuitable for binary arithmetic and also non-portable.

Comment: I've modified and tried it, but it still doesn't work, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Judy11432 Is the interrupt firing at all? Did you try to set a breakpoint inside the ISR?

Comment: Hi Lundin,I don't understand how to interrupt firing, sorry I just learned this stuff

Comment: @Judy11432 If you don't know how to use a debugger, you are probably better off learning the basics on a PC before moving on to embedded systems. But it isn't hard to learn, every debugger out there works similar no matter target.

Answer (score 2):

`timer_isr()` isn't set up as interrupt service routine.

You need to add the `interrupt` keyword:

```c
void interrupt timer_isr(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Without the `interrupt` keyword, `timer_isr()` is a regular function, which is never referenced in your program.

---

EDIT:

`void interrupt timer_isr(void)` is the correct syntax.

Deviations like `void __interrupt() timer_isr(void)` and `void __interrupt() INTERRUPT_InterruptManager(void)` are wrong.

The error message `main.c:49:: error: (1506) multiple interrupt functions (_timer_isr and _INTERRUPT_InterruptManager) defined at interrupt level 1` states that the timer interrupt service routine has already been defined somewhere else.

I've never used the MPLAB Code Configurator (MCC) before, but I strongly suspect that the corresponding code is being included with `#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"`. Have a look at that file to see if you can find the other definition of the timer interrupt service routine

Comment: I tried chang to `void interrupt timer_isr(void)` and `void __interrupt() timer_isr(void)`
The following error occurs : 
`main.c:49:: error: (1506) multiple interrupt functions (_timer_isr and _INTERRUPT_InterruptManager) defined at interrupt level 1`
So I chang to :
`void __interrupt() INTERRUPT_InterruptManager(void)`
this error will occur : 
`main.c:49:: error: (1098) conflicting declarations for variable "_INTERRUPT_InterruptManager" (mcc_generated_files/interrupt_manager.c:52)`
I have checked a lot of information, and my understanding is that variables cannot be added to it, right?